# Tests failing because of a 500 internal server error

Tags: jenkins, testing, codeception

```html
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:568 bytesOut:3062 reqTime:0
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/ng-file-upload-all.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 14565 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/ngBootbox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1407 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/bootbox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 4166 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/ngBootbox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:557 bytesOut:1407 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/bootbox.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:556 bytesOut:4166 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/ng-file-upload-all.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:567 bytesOut:14565 reqTime:0
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 20933 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/angular-moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2281 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/moment-locale-en-gb.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1385 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/smart-table/smart-table.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 2902 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/lrStickyHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 1905 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/lrStickyHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:559 bytesOut:1905 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/moment-locale-en-gb.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:563 bytesOut:1385 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/angular-moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:563 bytesOut:2281 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/smart-table/smart-table.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:572 bytesOut:2902 reqTime:0
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/moment.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:555 bytesOut:20933 reqTime:0
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/stStickyHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 816 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /assets/d5e561ce/js/stStickyHeader.js HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:558 bytesOut:816 reqTime:0
[php-fpm:access] 127.0.0.1 -  13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000 "GET /index.php?compDur=0+DAY&getKids=none&open=0&team=50&type=team" 200 /var/www/secure.curtisbanks.co.uk/htdocs/index.php 323.680 8192 30.89%
docker.vm:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /tasks/tasksApi/tasks?compDur=0+DAY&getKids=none&open=0&team=50&type=team HTTP/1.1" 200 57634 "http://servertest01:8082/apex/team/50" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
[httpd:access] servertest01:ip - - [13/Sep/2019:14:02:09 +0000] "GET /tasks/tasksApi/tasks?compDur=0+DAY&getKids=none&open=0&team=50&type=team HTTP/1.1" 200 bytesIn:587 bytesOut:576
```

So I have my tests running each morning at 3 AM aprox. I have some tests that are failing with the same error which is:

```
  03:12:18.785 WARNING - http://servertest/user/account/login - This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see https://goo.
  03:12:53.997 WARNING - http://servertest/user/account/login - This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see https://goo.
  03:13:18.146 SEVERE - http://servertest/portal/messages/team/id/46/view/onldgdl7g7SrCYl93uyGVFon1yfJP6OGpRpyiJmpQUYuoXKk - [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #undefined_hint: (More info: https://goo) %o %o
  03:13:25.395 SEVERE - http://servertest/portal/messages/exportForKW/ref/onldgdl7g7SrCYl93uyGVFon1yfJP6OGpRpyiJmpQUYuoXKk/ajax/1 - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I have tried to change the id's where is it filling the user name and password as I can see on the screenshot that the last part of the password is sometimes filled in the username filed, after the user name was already filled in.

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Search for a caller, go through security, save it and add notes');

//Log in
$I->amOnPage('/user/account/login');
$I->fillField("UserLogin[username]", "");
$I->fillField("UserLogin[password]", "");
$I->click('Log In');
$I->wait(2);
$I->waitForElementVisible('#AdminMemberGrid_status', 30);

//Access the call tab
$I->click('//*[@id="secondaryMenu"]/li[1]/a');
$I->waitForText('Search for caller :');
```

Here the popup where I wait for text search for caller and pick up transferred call is not visible, in the screenshot it barley appears in front of the first page when I click the Call tab `$I->click('//*[@id="secondaryMenu"]/li[1]/a');`

I am expecting to see the text and fill the fields, adding a longer wait won't make any difference.

The other tests pass, and they have the same code.

Clicking on the google links will redirect me to the security blog, online google security blog: 2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html

```
09:39:55.676 WARNING - http://servertest/user/account/login - This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see 
09:41:09.738 SEVERE - http://servertest/nii/index/show/id/144904/type/40x40.max - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
09:41:10.182 SEVERE - http://servertest/nii/index/show/id/144904/type/40x40.max - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
09:41:22.316 SEVERE - http://servertest/nii/index/show/id/144904/type/40x40.max - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
09:41:42.15 SEVERE - http://servertest/nii/index/show/id/144904/type/40x40.max - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
09:42:12.869 SEVERE - http://servertest/nii/index/show/id/144904/type/40x40.max - Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
09:42:29.88 WARNING - http://servertest/user/account/login - This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see 
09:43:04.33 WARNING - http://servertest/user/account/login - This page includes a password or credit card input in a non-secure context. A warning has been added to the URL bar. For more information, see 
09:43:30.640 SEVERE -  - [DOM] Found 2 elements with non-unique id #undefined_hint: (More info: ) %o %o
```

Comment: Check server side logs.

Comment: @Naktibalda can you be more specific? jenkins logs? what log should I be looking for? thank you for the answer!

Comment: Logs of your http daemon (apache, nginx, etc) and logs of your application if it is able to return status 500.

Comment: @Naktibalda I could not find anything useful , I had just some Apache log but nothing relevant in it.

Comment: If you are using php-fpm, try to find its logs. I am not familiar with fpm, but it makes harder to debug PHP issues. This is not a Codeception issue.

Comment: I might have something to do with chrome certificate as it's complaining about the link , that is not a https one, any ideas of this one?

Comment: I have still the same issue, the thing is that before this test, two other tests are doing the same thing, clicking on that specific menu, and waiting for the text. First two tests pass, the last one fails. I do a login every time I am running my tests. Any ideas?

Comment: @Naktibalda here is the log, it's on the first post from this page

Comment: It looks like you haven't found the log of the service which fails.

Comment: So I was looking on the docker container, the workspace_apache_1 container, should I be looking for something else?

Comment: This isn't the right place for debugging support.

Comment: Well I was trying to check the server side logs as you told me first time, I found something and I posted with a reply here. Thank you for the help.